# When attempting to redirect with httpget, it leaves the query string out of the url

Tags: html, get, query-string, shopify

I've got a shopify snippet that creates a button that is supposed to redirect the user to a web page that lets them customize their order. (That's not the actual url)

```
    <div class="customize-products">
      <form name="customize" method="get" action=".../kiosk.htm?sideid=2&productid=1&customerid=myname&returnurl=http://google.com/">
          <input type="submit" value="Customize">
      </form>
   </div>
```

It ends up going to that page, but leaves out everything after the question mark.

Comment: Also, using "post" instead is not an option because the domain it redirects to doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried making your link/button an anchor tag instead?

The stuff is being dropped because you are submitting a form and the form has no information in it.

Alternatively you could hide everything in hidden-fields

```
<form method="get" action=".../kiosk.html">
  <input type="hidden" name="sideid" value="2" />
  <input type="hidden" name="productid" value="1234" />
  <input type="submit" value="Customize" />
</form>
```

The added benefit of that is now it's easier to read/debug.

Comment: curious... what's   .../kiosk.html represent in a form action?